# Anova test number of files in system types, extremely small p-value

Tags: anova, python, p-value, dataset

To get more practice with Anova tests, I am attempting to use it on a dataset that I have, but the result that I have received has an incredibly small P-value (e^-62). Below is the result as well as the code I am using (python).  the values are normalized (they are percentages of a type of file in a system, so if a value is ex. "50.76", this means that 50.76% of the system has file type X).

There are 8 different system kinds, sysA thru sysH.  Looking through this Stats.Exchange seems to suggest that p-values this low suggest that there may be an error in the dataset.

```
                 N      Mean       SD      SE      95% Conf. Interval
system_types
     sysH         1004  40.1854  21.4486  0.6769    38.8571   41.5137
     sysA            5  53.3590   4.1002  1.8336    48.2680   58.4500
     sysB           25   6.4330   1.7581  0.3516     5.7073    7.1588
     sysC         1669  47.9986  15.0249  0.3678    47.2772   48.7199
     sysD          207  37.5900  18.9452  1.3168    34.9939   40.1861
     sysE          494  41.5398  12.3738  0.5567    40.4460   42.6336
     sysF          162  37.7636  18.8845  1.4837    34.8336   40.6937
     sysG           42  44.9685  16.5069  2.5471    39.8246   50.1124
     F_onewayResult(statistic=45.85906406165345, pvalue=1.363789164896136e-62)
```

the Code I am using is as follows:

```
    data = pd.read_csv(datafile)
    print(data)

    data.info()

    test = rp.summary_cont(data['binary'].groupby(data['system_types']))
    print(test)

    test = stats.f_oneway(data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysH'],
            data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysA'],
            data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysB'],
            data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysC'],
            data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysD'],
            data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysE'],
            data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysF'],
            data['binary'][data['system_types']=='sysG'])
    print(test)
```

The way I am calculating my dataset is for each system_type is:

```
    ((Number of files of type binary)/(Number of total files))*100
```

When doing this across the entire dataset for each system type the percentages are extremely close:

```
system_types
     sysH         28.54%
     sysA         28.89%   
     sysB         88.44%
     sysC         23.91%
     sysD         30.51%
     sysE         24.68% 
     sysF         29.31%
     sysG         13.05%
```

Given that the system_type wide percentages are relatively close (around 23%) I find it difficult to assume that these system_types are so different that p-value is 62 orders of magnitude different.  Is this possible? are there other tests I can do to confirm this finding? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Why in your first panel does sysB have a mean wildly different from the others and yet in the last panel they are similar?

Comment: Fixed. Now the percentages match the dataset that was used.  I see that SysB is significantly different. Is that what is causing it extremely small p-value?